# Unable to build Android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated the android studio application. Since then whenever I try to create a new project, it always fails to build as it gives the error: unable to resolve dependency as shown in the below figure.

[Here Is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnMU5.png)

[image]

I have tried many solutions provided online like uncheck the offline mode checkbox, add maven line in the gradle, but none works. Please suggest me with some solution.
I have already tried uninstalling and then installing the app. But that didn't work either too.

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint layout dependency in your app level build.gradle file

```
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0"
```